# How to evaluate if a date field is filled or empty in a form correctly?

Tags: java, gwt

**Context**
I have a form  (developed using Java and GWT) which has two fields (Intial Date and Final Date) and I want to evaluate them before sending the data to the server.

**Expected**
If one of the two fields is not set up, I get an error message

**Observed**
I get an error in the code during the compilation process due to it is not possible to get an string from a null value

The code:

```
Date beginValue = this.beginDateObj.getMyValue();
Date endValue = this.endDateObj.getMyValue();
      
if (((beginValue == null || beginValue.toString().isEmpty()) && ((endValue != null || !endValue.toString().isEmpty()))) ||
        ((beginValue != null || !beginValue.toString().isEmpty()) && ((endValue == null || endValue.toString().isEmpty())))) {
        myError.setText(constants.mandatoryFieldCombined2());
        myError.setVisible(true);
        isValid = false;
      }
```

I don't know what is incorrect in that code. I always think that the null comparison is the first thing the code evaluates and if it's true, it's not necessary to evaluate the rest of the comparison, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
(endValue != null || !endValue.toString().isEmpty())
```

If endValue is null, then endValue.toString() will be evaluated.

You want this:

```
(endValue != null && !endValue.toString().isEmpty())
```

or the logically equivalent:

```
(!(endValue == null || endValue.toString().isEmpty()))
```

You are also doing similar with beginValue futher on, that needs a similar correction.